# Highcharts - Treemap synchronisation onclick

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have two treemap highcharts that i want to synchronize, so if i drilldown into the lower one for 2013, i want to update the upper one for 2012 to drilldown into the same point.

I'm able to get the id when i click on the lower one, for example `id_5` for "South-East Asia". How can i trigger the drilldown or click event for the upper `container`?

https://jsfiddle.net/51xfq8ty/5/

Answer (score 0):

To synchronize the `drilldown` you can use internal `onClickDrillToNode` method with the right point as an argument. To synchronize the `drillup`, you need to overwrite `drillUp` method:

```
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function(event) {
                    chart.series[0].onClickDrillToNode({
                        point: chart.series[0].points[event.point.index]
                    });
                }

            }
        },
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1znbwpu7/